# How to get the 3D mouse pos in godot 4.1?

Tags: 3d, gdscript, godot4

How do I get the 3D mouse position in godot 4.1? Every thing ive tried dosent work and all the YT toutorials don't work!

I've tried to use documentation and YT toutorials. And i expected it to work!!!

I think its a problem with intersect_ray() function in godot because it only allows 1 argument instead of 2.

Answer (score 2):

You must be looking at Godot 3 tutorials. Be aware that since Godot 2 was very niche, many Godot 3 tutorials released before Godot 4 do not specify for which version of Godot they are.

About the documentation: you can the version of Godot for which you are reading the documentation in the bottom left, and also in the URL.

---

As per `intersect_ray`, the concept is the same, but the API is different. In particular: in Godot 3 `intersect_ray` takes many optional arguments. Bug for Godot 4 they were unified into an object.

So in GODOT 3 you would be doing something like this:

```
var space_state := get_world().direct_space_state
var result := space_state.intersect_ray(origin, end)
```

You can look at the documentation for [`intersect_ray` in Godot 3](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_physicsdirectspacestate.html#class-physicsdirectspacestate-method-intersect-ray) for the extra parameters. The article [Ray-casting (in Godot 3)](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/tutorials/physics/ray-casting.html) has further explanation.

The same in GODOT 4 would be like this:

```
var space_state := get_world_3d().direct_space_state
var query := PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D.create(origin, end)
var result := space_state.intersect_ray(query)
```

You can look at the [`PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.1/classes/class_physicsrayqueryparameters3d.html) class for the extra properties. The article [Ray-casting (in Godot 4)](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.1/tutorials/physics/ray-casting.html) has further explanation.

---

To get the position in 3D the mouse is hovering over in Godot 4, you first need to get the mouse position and the current `Camera3D`:

```
var viewport := get_viewport()
var mouse_position := viewport.get_mouse_position()
var camera := viewport.get_camera_3d()
```

Then we can get the origin and direction of the ray for that point:

```
var origin := camera.project_ray_origin(mouse_position)
var direction := camera.project_ray_normal(mouse_position)
```

Since we need origin and end, we compute end using the origin the direction, and some maximum length for the ray... Let us use `far` from the `Camera3D` for the length of the ray:

```
var ray_length := camera.far
var end := origin + direction * ray_length
```

And, of course, let us use `intersect_ray`:

```
var space_state := get_world_3d().direct_space_state
var query := PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D.create(origin, end)
var result := space_state.intersect_ray(query)
```

And, of course, read the position:

```
var mouse_position_3D:Vector3 = result["position"]
```

Which reminds me, if there was no intersection, you get an empty `Dictionary`, let us deal with that:

```
var mouse_position_3D:Vector3 = result.get("position", end)
```

Here if the result is empty (and thus, does not have a `"position"` key) you get the end of the ray as position.

---

Know that if you want to deal with this by other means, you can check if the result is empty instead:

```
var mouse_position_3D := end
if not result.is_empty():
    mouse_position_3D = result["position"]
```

Also, you can write `result.position` instead of `result["position"]`, but I'm using the latter here to highlight that it is a key in a `Dictionary`.

---

You can, of course make the code shorter (I broke it into simple steps for the explanation). You could use a more sensible ray length. And perhaps cache `viewport` so you don't have to get it every call... (you only would need to get it when the `Node` where this code is running enters the scene tree).

In fact, you can use `get_world_3d` on the `Viewport`, in case you don't want to run this code on a `Node3D`:

```
var space_state := viewport.get_world_3d().direct_space_state
```

And, of course, you can configure `PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D` to exclude objects, to intersect areas in addition (or instead of) bodies, and to have an specific collision mask.